# Using worksheet position and range.value

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a code that generates a workbook by copying and moving selected worksheets into a new workbook.
The first page of this new workbook is a summary page. On this i want to pull data from the subsequent worksheets by using the range.value method.
However can I use this when referencing the worksheet location for example

```
Dim wb As Workbook, wbAll As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wbAll = Workbooks.Add
On Error Resume Next
For t = 1 To 100         
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book" & t)
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        ws.Move after:=wbAll.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Next
Next
Workbooks("Book" & t).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select

'compile worksheets into list
Dim wss As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer

On Error Resume Next
 
x = 17
 
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c17:E46").ClearContents

 
For Each wss In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wss.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
         Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3) = wss.Name
         x = x + 1
    End If
Next wss

'COMPILE COSTS
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("C17").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(2).Range("Q118").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("C18").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(3).Range("Q118").Value
.
.
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("C45").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(30).Range("Q118").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("C46").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(31).Range("Q118").Value

'Compile WBS
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("D17").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(2).Range("D10").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("D18").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(3).Range("D10").Value
.
.
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("D45").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(30).Range("D10").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("D46").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(31).Range("D10").Value


'Week Number name
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("C10").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(2).Range("D4").Value
'Supplier Name
ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("C12").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(2).Range("D5").Value
```

This however gives me an error message of object defined error

Comment: What is the error message? Also, you should be aware that `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook with the macro. If you've generated a new workbook, then you are referencing the wrong workbook. For a more detailed answer, we'd need a minimal reproducible example of your code.

Comment: perhaps I should use activeworkbook as it deals with the workbook at the top of the deck?

Comment: also a bigger section of  the code has been added

Comment: Will the names of the workbooks be static or dynamic?

Comment: Brett - The workbook that the first part of the code generates are named as they are generated. ie if the code is run then it'll be 'book1' and the 'book2' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

**EDIT**: updated to show using links instead of copying the values from the sheet.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbAll As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wss As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer, wsSummary, t As Long
    
    Set wbAll = Workbooks.Add
    
    For t = 1 To 100
        Set wb = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next    'ignore any error
        Set wb = Workbooks("Book" & t)
        On Error GoTo 0         'cancel OERN as soon as possible
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then
            For Each ws In wb.Sheets
                ws.Move after:=wbAll.Sheets(wbAll.Sheets.Count)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    'Workbooks("Book" & t).Activate   'not sure what this is for?
    'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    
    'compile worksheets into list
    x = 17
    Set wsSummary = wbAll.Sheets("Sheet1")
    wsSummary.Range("C17:E46").ClearContents
    
    For Each wss In wbAll.Worksheets
        If wss.Name <> wsSummary.Name Then
             With wsSummary.Rows(x)
                '.Cells(3).Value = wss.Name
                InsertLink .Cells(5), wss.Range("A1"), "=SheetName({1})"
                '.Cells(4).Value = wss.Range("Q118").Value
                InsertLink .Cells(4), wss.Range("Q118")   'create a link
                '.Cells(5).Value = wss.Range("D10").Value
                InsertLink .Cells(5), wss.Range("D10")
                'etc etc
             End With
             x = x + 1
        End If
    Next wss

End Sub
'UDF to return the sheet name
Function SheetName(c As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    SheetName = c.Parent.Name
End Function

'Insert a worksheet formula into a cell (rngDest), where the precedents
'  are either a single cell/range or an array of cells/ranges (SourceRange)
'  sTemplate is an optional string template for the formula
'   eg. "=SUM({1},{2})" where {1} and {2} are ranges in SourceRange
'   Empty template defaults to "={1}"
'Useage:
'   InsertLink sht1.Range("A1"), Array(sht1.Range("B1"), sht1.Range("C1")), "=SUM({1},{2})"
Sub InsertLink(rngDest As Range, SourceRange As Variant, Optional sTemplate As String)
    Dim i As Long, sAddress As String, arrTmp As Variant
 
    If sTemplate = "" Then sTemplate = "={1}" 'default is a simple linking formula
    
    'got a single range, or an array of ranges?
    If TypeName(SourceRange) = "Range" Then
        arrTmp = Array(SourceRange) 'make an array from the single range
    Else
        arrTmp = SourceRange        'use as-is
    End If
    'loop over the input range(s) and build the formula
    For i = LBound(arrTmp) To UBound(arrTmp)
        sAddress = ""
        If rngDest.Parent.Name <> arrTmp(i).Parent.Name Then
            sAddress = "'" & arrTmp(i).Parent.Name & "'!"
        End If
        sAddress = sAddress & arrTmp(i).Address(False, False)
        sTemplate = Replace(sTemplate, "{" & CStr(i + 1) & "}", sAddress)
    Next i
    rngDest.Formula = sTemplate 'assign the formula
 End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant Tim. Fantastic work around

Comment: I'm working on the next part of this exercise and what we have so far is great but it doesn't allow the summary sheet to update its extracted values if the other sheets are amended. I think I'm looking for a way to put a formula into the cells of sheet1 to reference the sheets which make up the workbook. However as this created workbook is pulled from another workbook the sheet names are always different and the sheet numbers are always different. Would i have to use the worksheet position? I cant seem to get that to work

Comment: Instead of copying the links you can put a formula pointing to the source cell on the sheet in question.  That should work.

Comment: See updated code above.